# keyboard accessibility of hidden contents using css and html only

Tags: html, css, accessibility, keyboard-navigation

how can I make this snippet accessible?

```
<div tabindex="0">
    Show More
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Hidden Content</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Hidden Content</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Hidden Content</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div > ul
    {display:none;}
div:hover > ul, div:focus > ul
    {display:block;}
```

I wonder if it is possible to make `<ul>` visible also with keyboard navigation
while focusing its contents

http://jsfiddle.net/pJs2U/

Comment: No, `tabindex` minimum value is `0`: you are talking about `-1`, which means "not focusable". Also, I'm not navigating away. I'm still in the focused tree. I thought `:focus` worked like `:hover`, where you `:hover` an element as you are `:hover`ing its parent tree as well. `:focus` is enabled on target and on target only

Comment: Wes all of your `<a>`s need `tabindex=0` not just the container

Comment: no, by default all links are tabindex=0

Comment: is your question how to make that more accessible or how to make the list visible from keyboard navigation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update 2015** (thanks, @[JayMee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1017882/jaymee)): The current (2015-05-29) [Editor’s Draft](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors-4/) doesn’t contain this syntax/feature anymore. (The latest Working Draft [still does](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/WD-selectors4-20130502/#subject), but [it’s from 2013-05-02](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/WD-selectors4-20130502/).)

---

For the future:

In the [Working Draft of **Selectors Level 4**](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/) there is a way to [specify the subject](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-selectors4-20120823/#subject) of a selector (resp. [in the Editor’s Draft](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/#subject)).

I guess the following should work when browsers implement it (and if the syntax will not be changed):

```
!div a:focus
  {display:block;}
```

It selects a `div` element (notice the `!` in the selector) which has a focused `a` element as child.

---

[For JQuery, there is a polyfill](https://github.com/Idered/cssParentSelector) (but it uses the old syntax where the `!` was used as suffix, not prefix).

Comment: This, unfortunately, has been removed now. http://css4-selectors.com/selector/css4/subject-of-selector-with-child-combinator/

Comment: @JayMee: Thanks for the update! I added a note to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Changing a CSS property on the `<ul>` when a child element has focus is not possible using just HTML and CSS.

What you are describing would require a parent selector, but CSS3 does not support parent selectors [for performance reasons](http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/css-parent-selectors).

*Note*: You might consider a javascript solution. The vast majority of screen reader users [have javascript enabled](http://webaim.org/projects/screenreadersurvey3/#javascript). In jQuery it might look like:

```
$('a').on('focus blur', function(e) {
  $(this).parents('ul').toggle();
});
```

Comment: CSS [does support it](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#subject) (Working Draft), but user-agents probably not.

Comment: Thanks @unor, I updated the answer to reflect level 3 selectors.

Answer (score 1):

The javascript solution is the best. You can't depend on the focus of a parent to display a child. This falls apart as soon as you move focus.

Adding and removing a class from the parent gives you much more control. Dirk Ginader spoke of this as the fifth layer of accessibility http://www.slideshare.net/ginader/the-5-layers-of-web-accessibility